# Sum of harmonic numbers $H_{n+k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, harmonic-numbers, sums-of-squares

I'm trying to take that sum: $$\sum_{k=1}^n H_{n+k}$$
So I transformed this sum to such: $\sum_{i=1}^n iH_{2n+1-i}$, unfortunately i can't make this sum out :(
Hope You can help me, Thanks for attention!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could replace $H_{n+k}$ with its definition and then change the order of summation.

A little bit simpler way is to note that your sum is $S_{2n}-S_n$, where $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}H_k=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{j}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=j}^{n}\frac{1}{j}\\=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{n+1-j}{j}=(n+1)H_n-n.$$

Comment: (Yet another way is to use summation by parts - it's funny but I see incorrect formulae in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts).)

Comment: Thank You:)))))